# Dolphin Mount ISO - Where does it go?

Tags: mount, software-installation, kde, iso, dolphin

With the latest version of Dolphin, you can right-click ISOs and select "Mount":
[image: Screenshot of the Mount option]

But it doesn't appear anywhere on the sidebar or in the device notifier. Does anywhere know where it goes so I can use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug in an early release of the Dolphin ISO mounter. Now, mounted ISOs appear under Devices, or at `/run/media/$USER/isoname`:

[image]